# JQuery AJAX access data sent with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have this AJAX:

```
                $.ajax({
                    url : get_base_url() + 'update',
                    type : 'POST',
                    async : false,
                    data : json_positions,
                    dataType : 'html',
                    success : function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('error:');
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(errorThrown)
                    }
                });
```

data sent is:

> json_positions

which is a string like this:

```
{"new_positions" : [{ "id": "2", "position": "0"},{ "id": "5", "position": "1"},{ "id": "4", "position": "2"}]}
```

I want to decode json_positions using json_decode() in a PHP page but it seem that tdata is not sent to the php page because when i try to:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

it returns an empty array using console.log(data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your code is okay, no need to change anything. But it's how you pass your data.

> data sent is: `json_positions` which is a string like this: ...

You should not pass it like *string*. It should be an **object** like you defimed it:

```
{"new_positions" : [{ "id": "2", "position": "0"},{ "id": "5", "position": "1"},{ "id": "4", "position": "2"}]}
```

Make you sure you pass **an object**, not string, e.g. don't add any quotes around it etc. Then it's going to work fine.

#### EDIT

As per jQuery documentation for **$.ajax data parameter**:

> dataObject, String
>   Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

So your data should be a query string or an object.

In your case I recommend to use object. Like with this code:

```
var json_positions = {
    new_positions: []
};
$.each(result, function(key, value) {
    var value_splitted = value.split('-');
    json_positions.new_positions.push({
        id: value_splitted[1],
        position: key
    });
});
```

Comment: it hasn't any type of quotes, it's created using: var json_positions = '{';
     json_positions += '"new_positions" : ['
     $.each(result, function(key, value) {
      var value_splitted = value.split('-');
      json_positions += '{ "id": "' + value_splitted[1] + '", "position": "' + key + '"}';
      if(key != result.length - 1) {
       json_positions += ',';
      }
     });

Comment: Okay, this is what i'm talking about. You should pass an object as your data, not string. So instead of creating a string just create an object.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sending json data, you need to define the appropriate content type:

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

Also, change the dataType to json if you are expecting json data back:

```
dataType : 'json'
```

Comment: dataType is for the data being sent from the server to the client not the one sent from ajax

Comment: Note: jQuery actually intelligently guesses the `dataType` param, but it is definitely safer to specify.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` only contains key value pair stuff. Your POSTed JSON is in `$_HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`.